# Validating JSON with Play: How to generate possible missing data

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following `Reads` that validates the JSON representation of an user...

```
val userValidator: Reads[JsValue] = (
  (__ \ 'id).readNullable[Int] ~ // how do I invoke Random.nextInt if 'id is missing?
  (__ \ 'name).read[String]
).tupled ~> implicitly[Reads[JsValue]]
```

... how do I generate the `id` key if not specified in the input JSON? Let's suppose the input JSON is something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Joe
}
```

How do I add the `id` key and generate its value with `Random.nextInt`, so that the resulting JSON is something like this?

```
{
  "id": 153876748,
  "name": "Joe"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my projects, I have defined the following method :

```
def withDefault[A](key: String, default: =>A)(implicit writes: Writes[A]) = 
    __.json.update((__ \ key).json.copyFrom((__ \ key).json.pick orElse Reads.pure(Json.toJson(default))))
```

Then you can write :

```
  val _userValidator = (
    (__ \ 'id).readNullable[Int] ~
      (__ \ 'name).read[String]
    ).tupled  ~> implicitly[Reads[JsValue]]
  val userValidator = _userValidator.compose(withDefault("id",Random.nextInt ))
```

Which should do what you asked :

```
scala> userValidator.reads(Json.parse("""{"name": "Joe"}"""))
res6: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = JsSuccess({"name":"Joe","id":721872039},)
```